# How to setup local cluster for MBrace

Tags: azure, f#, cloud, mbrace

I'm trying to follow tutorials on using MBrace with f# (one is [here (youtube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hP3NkOVNxFE&spfreload=1). The problem is that with all the videos I've seen, they are either using Azure or running some form of local cluster on the machine.

Since I'll not be using Azure now, how do I setup a local cluster which I can use to test mbrace locally without having to go online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test MBrace with a local cluster on your machine you can 
git clone https://github.com/mbraceproject/MBrace.Core and for a sample check this https://github.com/mbraceproject/MBrace.Core/blob/master/samples/wordcount.fsx

One important note is that we are currently working towards MBrace 1.0 and you may find some API differences between MBrace.Core and MBrace.StarterKit (https://github.com/mbraceproject/MBrace.StarterKit)

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. Got some samples running just fine. Did notice some api differences but they are quite easy to reason about. As you work towards 1.0, should we be expecting additional api changes?